# Email Pipe with Aliases Created Programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, imap, centos

I have a dedicated server with MediaTemple. I'm searching for an efficient way to create email aliases programmatically in PHP.

The server has Plesk installed so I originally thought I could use the Plesk CLI to create an email alias that piped to a PHP script, but the only method I've found with the CLI is to create an email account.

My ideal situation is:

PHP script progammatically creates an email alias that forwards to a PHP script that handles email piping.

What I would like to know is some of the accepted methods of doing this. For instance facebook allows you to create a facebook email account alias that you can use to update your status and post photos by just sending an email to that account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this, but not with Plesk.

You should be able to add aliases to your `/etc/aliases` file, then you might need to run `newaliases` as a user with the correct privileges (I've done this as root; maybe you could cron it).

The alias would look something like this:

```
aliasname: "|/path/to/mailhandler.php"
```

`mailhandler.php` needs to be `+x` (chmod), and should probably start with `#!/usr/bin/env php`; from there you can read from the `php://stdin` stream and parse the headers and/or body to do what you need.

Comment: Exactly the idea I was going for.

Comment: @Tegan: If scoates has answered the question to your satisfaction, click the Checkmark to the left of his answer to mark it as correct. It means he will be rewarded for his time, and the question will no longer showup in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: thanks Lucanos.. kind of frustrating to answer a question, get "exactly what I was going for" and not even a +1. /-:

Comment: suppose I host multiple domains, how can I deconflict hi@example1.com and hi@example2.com?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it using the Plesk CLI if you read page 163 of the Plesk Command Line Interface document you'll see this;

the code would be

```
echo exec('> ls /path/to/plesk/ >mail.exe --update JohnDoe@example.com -aliases  add:JD,JohnD');
```

you'll need to make to multipl shell calls on the CLI this will help. http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/428-executing-multiple-shell-commands-via-one-exec-call

the two commands you'll need are:

- ls /path/to/plesk/
- mmail.exe --update JohnDoe@example.com -aliases  add:JD,JohnD');

Comment: I wish there was just a newaliases command on the server. I could just edit the /etc/aliases file and run that... but I'm not finding one... I think I may need to use the CLI. MediaTemple appears to be running qmail MTA with plesk